# AutoCompleteBox: do not validate with Up/Down keys

Tags: silverlight, autocompletebox, selectionchanged

My AutoCompleteBox calls a WCF service when the selection is changed, usually with the mouse. However if the user uses the arrow keys to navigate through the selection, the event fires up for each element, making the application too much data intensive.
How do I prevent the AutoCompleteBox_SelectionChanged to fire when the keys are pressed?

I found this which sounded like a nice solution but it doesn't work http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/137710/307786.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, rather than using AutoCompleteBox_SelectionChanged, I'm using AutoCompleteBox_DropDownClosed, and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just found how I have solved this same problem. Also I am not using SelectionChanged.
I added behavior to item DataTemplate (to Grid root). This behavior attach click handler to item. When keys are used, behavior is "sleeping", when I click on item with mouse, behavior get called and make its work. (Also I bind needed property of item to a DataTemplate's Grid's Tag property, so I can get to it from behavior)

Not suitable for every solution, but can be useful.